# Lazy stateful processing with sequence libraries

Tags: clojure

Let's say I want to process a sequence, where the processing is stateful, and I want to do this in a lazy way using the Clojure sequence libraries.

As a concrete example, assume I want to implement `distinct`, which is naturally implemented as a stateful filter, keeping track of the elements seen. My first stab is to make no use of sequence libraries, but instead `lazy-seq`:

```
(defn distinct' [coll]
  (let [process (fn process [coll seen]
                  (lazy-seq
                    (when-let [[x & r] (seq coll)]
                      (if (contains? seen x)
                        (process r seen)
                        (cons x (process r (conj seen x)))))))]
    (process coll #{})))
```

I'm OK with the above, but, I'd prefer to instead make use of methods like `map` and `filter` if I can. I'm struggling with how to do this cleanly. One approach that works is to make use of `reductions`:

```
(defn distinct'' [coll]
  (->> (reductions (fn [[_ _ seen] x]
                     (if (contains? seen x)
                       [false nil seen]
                       [true x (conj seen x)]))
                   [false nil #{}]
                   coll)
       (filter first)
       (map second)))
```

Fundamentally, `distinct''` fulfills the goal of using higher-level abstractions (`map`, `filter`, `reductions`) while remaining lazy. But it fails in being overly complex, especially with the vector I have it passing along as the accumulator.

If I try to directly embed state in a predicate to be used with `filter`, while it is closer to what I'm imagining, it just seems to be "wrong", and I'm embarrassed to even write the following code (`filter`'s docs even say that the predicate should be free of side effects):

```
(defn distinct''' [coll]
  (let [seen (atom #{})]
    (filter (fn [x]
              (if (contains? @seen x)
                false
                (do (swap! seen conj x)
                    true)))
            coll)))
```

My question:

Is there a way to do lazy stateful processing like this with sequence libraries in a clean way (even for this `distinct` example)? Or, is `lazy-seq` often the cleanest approach?

Comment: Seems like it's a matter of opinion. I think the lazy-seq approach is clearer.

Comment: My 0.02$: I don't think the last one is wrong, I don't understand mutating *internal* state as *side effects* and it's a very readable implementation, but agreed that it's a matter of opinion at all

Comment: As an aside, you should avoid using `[x & xs]` destructuring when producing a lazy seq from another lazy seq, because it forces *two* elements from the input seq, in order to find out if `xs` should be nil or not, which could be bad if `xs` is expensive to produce. For library-quality code, you kinda have to use `first` and `rest`.

Comment: Good point! As an aside: I'm intrigued by the concept of having a "reference implementation" that is simplest to reason about for correctness, along with a "production" or "library" implementation that is optimized, perhaps compared to the reference impl via `test.check`. I find the the shipping implementation of `distinct` fascinating with its internal `loop`/`recur` to avoid the `lazy-seq` when looking for novel elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like `distinct'`, although I would inline the `process` helper function, like `((fn process ...) coll #{})`. There's nothing wrong with using lazy-seq and recursion to solve a problem, and attempting to avoid them by making everything into `map`/`filter` can lead to much less readable programs.

And if you don't mind pulling in flatland/useful, you can make it a bit prettier with [lazy-loop](https://github.com/flatland/useful/blob/develop/src/flatland/useful/seq.clj#L108):

```
(defn distinct'''' [coll]
  (lazy-loop [coll coll, seen #{}]
    (when-let [[x & r] (seq coll)]
      (if (contains? seen x)
        (recur r seen)
        (cons x (lazy-recur r (conj seen x)))))))
```

which macroexpands to something equivalent to your `distinct'`.